# Is it possible to qualify a VBA function call with its module name in an Access query?

Tags: ms-access, vba, user-defined-functions

I have 2 public VBA functions `Module1.Foo` and `Module2.Foo`.

Is it possible to use either `Foo` function in an Access query? What is the syntax for qualifying the function call with the module name?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. But you could create a helper function for the purpose:

```
Public Function Module2_Foo(<params>)
    Module2_Foo = Module2.Foo(<params>)
End Function
```

Comment: I guess the helper function is almost as good as renaming the original function.

Comment: Yes, from a performance view, I can't think you'll notice any difference. It is rather a question about dilemmas in organising code.